# How can I draw nested shape, one on top another

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

For example, I want to draw a green rectangle with some black circles along the central horizontal axis of it. My main problem is how to let the circles appear on top of the rectangle.

Comment: What do you mean by `appear on top of the rectangle`? Do you mean the circles should appear 3-D above the rectangle? Or simply the circles hide the rectangle. Besides, the rectangle is filled green or just the stroke is green? The same for the circles? Please clarify or put an image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As @AboAmmar mentioned, please clarify what you want. Adding an image with the desired result would be helpful. It would also be really helpful if you could post the code of what you have tried so far. This will give us a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: Hard to help with so little information, but probably you inverted the order: draw the background _first_, then what comes on top.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have figured that out - the order of drawing is important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a green rectangle with black circles along the center:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you draw the circles *after* the square they will automatically be on top. Perhaps you had drawn the circles before the rectangle.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=green] (0,-1) rectangle (3,1);
\draw [radius=0.2cm,fill=black]  (0.5,0) circle;
\draw [radius=0.2cm,fill=black]  (1.5,0) circle;
\draw [radius=0.2cm,fill=black]  (2.5,0) circle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```